# Indy TCPClient OnDisconnect event not working

Tags: delphi, networking, tcpclient, indy

```
type
  TForm8 = class(TForm)
    idtcpclnt1: TIdTCPClient;
    idtcpsrvr1: TIdTCPServer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure idtcpsrvr1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure idtcpclnt1Disconnected(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form8: TForm8;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm8.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  idtcpclnt1.Connect;
end;

procedure TForm8.idtcpsrvr1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.Disconnect(true); //this gets called
end;

procedure TForm8.idtcpclnt1Disconnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('true'); //but this does not
end;
```

The OnDC never gets handled. Why?

Answer (score 12):

Indy client components are not event-driven (with a couple of exceptions, such as `TIdTelnet`).  The `TIdTCPClient.OnDisconnect` event is NOT triggered when the server disconnnects on its end, like you are assuming.  This is by design.  `TIdTCPClient` will not know about the disconnection until it tries to access the socket again, at which time it will raise an exception, such as `EIdConnClosedGracefully`.  The `TIdTCPClient.OnDisconnect` event is only triggered when the `TIdTCPClient.Disconnect()` method is called on the client side, which you are not doing.

In order to detect server-side disconnects with `TIdTCPClient`, you have to read from the socket periodically, such as in a timer or a separate thread.

Comment: This is really quite unsatisfactory. If there is an OnDisconnect event then one would expect it to be raised in all cases as soon as there is a disconnection (and not just when disconnect is called in which case the event is not informing the application of anything). Having to use a timer to poll for connection closures by doing dummy reads is really quite ugly and causes other undesirable side effects. There just seems to always be a lot of extra effort (i.e. code) needed to make Indy work properly. Shouldn't such a library be taking care of things for us?

Comment: @PeterBall "*This is really quite unsatisfactory.*" - like it or not, [that is how Indy is designed](https://web.archive.org/web/20180417064108/http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=index.html) (read the "Introduction to Indy" page). Events are meant for asynchronous handling, but Indy clients are primarily meant to be used synchronously instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my mistake. You code does not work, but that is correct. Let me explain why:

The `AContext.Connection.Disconnect(true)` method calls `DisconnectNotifyPeer` wich is not implemented in TCPServer. Why? Because it should not.

When you disconnect in the server, what indy does is invalidate the socket and close it. The client will only notice that the server disconnected when it tries to send some request. And you code does not do that. This is a default behavior of indy.

In order to notify the client that the server disconnected, indy and any other suites should implement what we call `heartbeat`. Heartbeat is a technique that from time to time tries to send small packets to an socket in order to detect that it is still alive. The only way of detect a socket disconnection is trying to write something in that socket. Google about `heartbeat` and you will understand what I mean.

**EDIT**

Check [this](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?messageID=245209) out.

Comment: Current version is the one that ships with Delphi XE. Can you give me your version?

Comment: Problem: Server is not designed by me, so I can't send any packets to it or it will DC current connection

Comment: @netboy I did not understand what you said. You should not worry about servers disconnection because indy handles it for you. Are you getting any error? What is exactly what is happening to you?

Comment: Check this out. -> The specified message [245209] was not found.

Comment: @RafaelColucci no need to send small heartbeat packets. If the remote end closes the connection then the appropriate packets have already been exchanged and the local operating system knows that the connection has been closed. Unfortunately Indy is not forwarding this on to the application unless the application goes out of its way to probe the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the **client** POLL for disconnection by adding a timer routine to the **client** - this is the SIMPLEST way.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
   begin                    
      idTCPClient1.Connected;  // Works in Indy for Delphi XE4
   // Be aware this is a property read with side effects
   // It shouldn't get optimized out, but if it does, 
   // then add the appropriate directives to prevent that.
   end;
```

This should make the code behave just like the old TClientSocket used to (and like the TidTelnet does). It produces a hsDisconnected flag to the OnStatus event if the server suddenly disappears (i.e. as soon as the firing timer routine detects this).  However, this special case of server-loss causing the disconnect does NOT fire the OnDisconnect event - just the OnStatus.  So it is probably better to always use OnStatus to trap all disconnections, be they client or server induced.  I used a timer set at 100ms, but I guess you can make it as frequent or slow as you want - it doesn't appear to do any harm.

NOTE:  FOR DELPHI 7 (and possibly other versions between D7 and XE4), you will have to do this slightly differently:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
   begin                    
   // This no longer works this way in Indy for XE4, but works in Indy for D7 ... 
      idTCPClient1.CheckForGracefulDisconnect(FALSE);  
   end;
```

By the way - if you're using Delphi 6, forget Indy, it was just way too buggy back then.

Comment: If you use Delphi 6 or 5, you do not have to forget Indy - you can use the current 10.6 release of Indy instead of the original Indy bundled with these old Delphi versions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I did read that somewhere and have been mulling over whether it is better to leave earlier Delphi's with their original Indy installs or upgrade them all.  Apparently upgrading them all runs the risk of breaking other dependent stuff, and of course you lose the ability to try out old code that uses incompatible Indy installations.  The API has never been what one could call stable!

Comment: Incidentally, since I wrote this contribution I have discovered that doing the actual poll for data in the timer has an identical effect.   Say: CheckForDataOnSource(100{ms}); if InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;  This would make iDTCPClient1.Connected unnecessary.